# Vtiger module creator hidden module issue Freez Bage module layouts & fileds

Tags: php, module, crm, vtiger, issue-tracking

Iam using vtiger 7.4.0
I trayed to create module with the original tool Vtiger , enabled from connect SSH with php and enabled the module creator tool and add name and file name but i cant fined the module in home menu , i fined it in
(( module layouts & fileds )) but I cant edit any thing and have a freez with clik mouse i cant move to add relationship or add any field just freez all page
thanks,

vtiger module creator

Comment: Please share the code involved

Comment: php -f vtlib/tools/consol.php    1- create module = 1     enter module name = CustommerDiyarV      name = custommerDiyar

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

So the installation was correct?
Try access by URL, something like this:  domain.com/index.php?module=ModuleName&view=List

If everything is correct you can run a vtlib to populate. This is just a reference:

```
 $moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance($MODULENAME);
 $menuInstance = Vtiger_Menu::getInstance('Tools');
 $menuInstance->addModule($moduleInstance);
```

or something like this:

`

```
$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance($MODULENAME);
$APPNAME = 'TOOLS';

if ($moduleInstance) {

    $adb->pquery("DELETE FROM vtiger_app2tab WHERE tabid = ?", array($moduleInstance->getId()));

    $adb->pquery(
        "INSERT INTO vtiger_app2tab (tabid, appname, sequence) SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?, ?, ?) AS tmp
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vtiger_app2tab WHERE tabid = ? AND appname = ?) LIMIT 1", 
        array($moduleInstance->getId(), $APPNAME, $sequence, $moduleInstance->getId(), $APPNAME)
    );

}
```

`

Comment: Its local host i trayed access with  { http://192.168.100.206/vtigercrm/index.php?module=CustommerDiyarV&view=List } but have this erorr  { Permission to perform the operation is denied for name : CustommerDiyarV }

Comment: i tray add new file module name in [ vtigercrm/modules ] and copy files from              
  [vtilib / moduleDir/6.0.0] and get code in 2 file { ModuleName.php  } from another serch but have issue  the admin user only can login to the system all user cant login

Comment: the installation not correctly and tray this and have issue  attach the issue link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75865092/vtiger-some-user-cant-login-admin-user-only-can-login